# Struggling with regular expression, removing number from string

Tags: php, regex

I have a number of strings such as these:

`Virtus.pro (13)`

`mousesports (16)`

`Natus Vincere (12)`

As you can see these is no really common way splitting the name from the number in all cases. 
I'm really new to Regex. Does anyone have any ideas how I could split these strings to contain 2 variables?

`Virtus.pro` and `13`. then `mousesports` and `16`?

As you can see the `Natus Vincere` one has a space between the two parts of the name.

Really struggling, I've only been able to come up with a regex for extracting the number. But this doesn't work everytime.

Comment: If you're struggling with writing or researching the regex, you could just use `rtrim()` and specify `"0123456789() "` to strip.

Comment: This should cover it `/^(.+) \((\d+)\)$/`

Comment: try this one `^([^\(]+)\(([0-9]+)\)$`

Comment: I think the shortest you can get to capture the opening parenthesis till the closing parenthesis and numbers in between is `(\(\d+\))`

Comment: http://regexr.com/39i8n

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$data = [
    "Virtus.pro (13)",
    "mousesports (16)",
    "Natus Vincere (12)"
];

foreach ($data as $string) {
    $matches = [];
    preg_match('/(.*)\s\((\d+)\)/', $string, $matches);
    list(, $team, $score) = $matches;
    var_dump($team, $score);
}
```

Output:

```
string(10) "Virtus.pro"
string(2) "13"
string(11) "mousesports"
string(2) "16"
string(13) "Natus Vincere"
string(2) "12"
```

The idea is to look for a substring followed by a space, opening parenthesis, some digits, and a closing parenthesis. The leading substring and the digits are snagged up in capturing groups then spit out into `$team` and `$score`.

Answer (score 1):

```
r'([a-zA-Z. ]+) (\(\d{1,2}\))'
```

I tried this one in python, it works for me. 
You'd better provide more details I think, for example, the format of the names, which kind of punctuation it contains, and the number, how many digits it has, etc.

In my answer above, the name string can contains '.' and ' ', and the number will be 1 or 2 digits.
you can change it to

```
r'([a-zA-Z. ]+) \((\d+)\)'
```

to match a number that you don't know how many digits it contains.
it groups the match results by the way, the second group (index 1) is the name, the third group (index 2) is the number.

```
>>> import re
>>> are=re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z. ]+) \((\d{1,2})\)')
>>> d=are.search('Virtus.pro (13)')
>>> d.group()
'Virtus.pro (13)'
>>> d.group(1)
'Virtus.pro'
>>> d.group(2)
'13'
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use something like this

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import re
    regex = re.compile('^(.*)\((\d+)\)$')
    my_match = regex.match('Virtus.pro (13)')
```

You can then do:

```
    m.group(1) #to get 'Virtus.pro '

    m.group(2) #to get '13'
```

This is implemented in python btw